# My subdomain will redirect to root domain. How do I fix this?

Tags: redirects, dns, subdomain

My Subdomain will redirect back to the main site. How do I fix this so it redirects to the subdomain? My main site is a WordPress adult site so I'll use example.com to explain. All I have in the subdomain directory is an index.php file with phpinfo().

I have a website at www.example.com. I set up a Virtual host file in /etc/apache2/sites-available and did the command: a2ensite example.com.conf. Then I restarted apache2.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
  ServerAdmin admin@example.com
  ServerName  subdomain.example.com
  ServerAlias www.subdomain.example.com
  Redirect / https://subdomain.example.com

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
  DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain
  # Log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /var/www/subdomain/log/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/subdomain/log/access.log combined

  <Location /server-status>
     SetHandler server-status
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from all
     Allow from localhost
  </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

In DNS tab on Cloudflare, I have an AAAA record and an A record with Subdomain in the name field and the server IP address in the value field. I have entries for the subdomain and also www.subdomain.

Comment: I change permission so that www-data owns the subdomain directory and now I get a 403 Forbidden error. Anyone know how to fix this? Do I need a .htaccess file?

Comment: I was able to ping the site.

Comment: I was able to get subdomain.rootdomain.com to work by copying and pasting the -ssl.conf file and enabling it. However, www.subdomain.rootdomain.com doesn't work still. Both are set up in DNS on Cloudflare and I am able to ping both. Anyone know why it doesn't work with www preceding the subdomain?

Comment: www.example.com you might want to setup as an alias, but why do you need www.subdomain.example.com ? if subdomain.example.com will be indexed, and use subdomain.example.com in your promotional info then www.subdomain.example.com is superfluous. there's literally no point in having it.

Comment: The question is not very clear!  Do you want http://www.subdomain.example.com to redirect to https://subdomain.example.com ?  And, https://www.subdomain.example.com to redirect to https://subdomain.example.com ? I think the first one should work as per your Apache configuration, but the second might not work.

Comment: Only the `<VirtualHost *:80>` container is shown in the question and this simply redirects everything to HTTPS - so we would need to see the `<VirtualHost *:443>` container also.

Answer (score 0):

In Apache's **SSL config for subdomain.example.com**, add a redirect for https://www.subdomain.example.com:

```
ServerAlias www.subdomain.example.com #make sure alias is present

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.subdomain\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://subdomain.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```